# Sidecaption in memoir in wrong margin when floated to next page

Tags: memoir

I'm currently building a template where I want to have floating captions in the margin. For the template I'm using the memoir class and for the captions it's sidecaption environment. I've set the `\sidecapmargin` to `outer`.

Still, when there is a lot of text on one page and e.g. the figure is floated to the next page, the sidecaption ends up in the wrong margin.

How can I fix this?

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside]{memoir}

%%% Layout the Page %%%
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
%\settypeblocksize{49\baselineskip}{107mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27.4mm}{*}{1}
\setlrmarginsandblock{24mm}{79mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{9mm}{50mm}{1em}
\setheadfoot{1.25\baselineskip}{10mm}
\setheaderspaces{*}{8mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\setsidecaps{\marginparsep}{\marginparwidth}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \lipsum[2] \lipsum[3] \lipsum[4] \lipsum[5]
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{sidecaption}{Test}
\missingfigure{Test}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: test if adding `\strictpagechecktrue` in your document preamble solve your problem.

Comment: @Zarko indeed that fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear this. i will convert my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\sidecapmargin` in cases when captions had to be on outside (or inside) page  margin had to check final page number, where the float is positioned. this is done by adding `\strictpagechecktrue` in document preamble. it is based on `pageref` mechanism. so it can happen that for correct positioning of `sidecaption` you need to compile document twice.